# Draw segments and circles with lineTo and arc - fill issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to make an animation with HTML5 Canvas where I draw the position of 3 segments, each others being joined with a circle.

The positions of each circle is determined by (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3).

Here my code snippet :

```
      context.fillStyle = 'white';
      context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 320);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x0, y0);
      context.lineTo(x1, y1);
      context.lineTo(x2, y2);
      context.lineTo(x3, y3);
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      context.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      context.arc(x3, y3, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fill();
```

Here's below the starting positions of these segments :

(x0,y0) is the top point coordinates which never change during animation.

Now, after some iterations, I get the following figure :

As you can see, my code fills a triangle between the 3 points (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3).

I don't want to fill this, I just want to draw the 3 segments and fill only the 3 circles for each iteration.

What's wrong with the above code snippet ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

An arc() is just a path, obliviously circular, but with two open ends. This causes it to append to the previous path point. When a fill() is issued the main path is closed causing the first arc end to connect to the first arc start point.

## Solution

You can solve it by creating sub-paths for the arcs. Insert a moveTo() for each arc which starts at angle 0 (also remove the last boolean for CCW so it draws clock-wise). Calling closePath() when we're dealing with sub-paths will cause the *sub-path* to close ends, which is good in our case as we can then close the start point set with moveTo() which happens to correspond with the start point of the arc, and is then connected to the end-point of the arc.

## Example

```
 context.beginPath();

 context.moveTo(x1 + radius, y1);  // create a new sub-path
 context.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 context.closePath();              // closes the current sub-path

 context.moveTo(x2 + radius, y2);  // create a new sub-path
 context.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 context.closePath();              // closes the current sub-path

 context.moveTo(x3 + radius, y3);  // create a new sub-path
 context.arc(x3, y3, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
 context.closePath();              // closes the current sub-path

 // fill all sub-paths
 context.fillStyle = 'blue';
 context.fill();  // would normally close the main path, but now we only have sub-paths
```

Comment: With your solution, only the circles are drawn, not the 3 segments, do you forget anything ?

Comment: ok, I have drawn the segments with another part, after your solution, thanks !

Comment: @user37422 yes, the part with the segments aren't shown in the answer, only the problematic part of the code.